# sql query in a performant way

Tags: sql

In my case there is a table called ServiceCarrier as below:

```
ServiceId CarrierId

1         1  
2         1  
4         1  
1         2  
2         2  
5         2   
1         20028  
2         20028  
5         20028
```

I want to group it by CarrierId and want to get the intersection in between grouped ones.
my expected result is as below

```
ServiceId 
1  
2
```

Comment: Please don't post your sample data as a link, or image. Post it as **text**. To help others help you, however, you need to expand more here. What is your expected result set? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Larnu thanks for the information.I updated the question according to it appreciate your help.

Comment: what do you mean by `want to get the intersection in between grouped ones` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I didn't down vote, but your question is getting down-voted because it doesn't include enough detail for us to help you. Please take a moment to read these two links, then consider editing your question if you're still looking for help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @EricBrandt thanks for the information.

Comment: Can you stop editing your question now?  It's up to 17 versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming (`serviceid`, `carrierid`) is unique. `GROUP BY serviceid` and get the `count(*)`. This will tell how many carriers do offer the service. Since you want only services offered by all carriers, limit the result in a `HAVING` clause to only keep the services, which have a count equal to the count of all carriers. That indicates the service is offered by all carriers.

```
SELECT serviceid
       FROM elbat
       GROUP BY serviceid
       HAVING count(*) = (SELECT count(DISTINCT carrierid)
                                 FROM elbat);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dfdae/5)

Answer (score 0):

To get what you wrote as 'expected' and 'intersection', perhaps try this?

> select serviceID from TSO where serviceID=carrierID

If you would like an aggregation, for example, count or sum, perhaps try this?

> select serviceID, count(carrierID) as count from TSO where
>   serviceID=carrierID group by serviceID